# Interpolation in temporal direction

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying now to do interpolation in `t` (temporal) direction. I have a matrix `Y` with `100*100*3`. The first slice is `Y` values at time `2` sec, the second slice is `Y` values at time `4` second and the third slice is `Y` values at time `7` sec . I am trying to get `Y` values at `3.4` sec and `5.7` sec

For example,

```
at time 2 sec Y(:,:,1)
at time 4 sec Y(:,:,2)
at time 7 sec Y(:,:,3)
```

I am trying to interpolate with respect to time. I used

```
Y_3_4 = interp2(X,Y,V,3.4)
Y_5_7 = interp2(X,Y,V,5.7)
```

I just update my question

```
Y_3_4 = interp3(Y(1,:),Y(:,1),3.4)
```

It is not working

```
Y_3_4 = interpn(1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [2, 4], Y, 1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [3.4]);
```

update code for 3.4

```
y_3_4 = interpn(1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [2, 4], Y, 1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [3.4]);
```

Thanks

Comment: interp3?  Its the 3rd dimension

Comment: @Ander Biguri. Thank you. I tried it is still not working

Comment: @user6052232 that's because there's a typo. `1;size(Y,2)` should be `1:size(Y,2)` in both cases. Shai just fixed it, try again.

Comment: BTW saying "this is not working" without explicitly say what error you get, or describing what happened is not very useful.

Comment: @interpn and Shi. Thank you so much for both of you. Please, should the code be [2 4] or [2 4 7]? Thanks

Comment: you need to put [2,4,7] because Y is explicitly of 3 elements in the 3rd dimension and you need to interpolate the whole object. so [2,4] by itself will give an error. If you try Shai's version it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`interpn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html)?
For `t=3.4`:

```
y_3_4 = interpn(1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [2, 4, 7], Y, 1:size(Y,1), 1:size(Y,2), [3.4]);
```

Comment: @interpn.Thank you, Please, if I need it for each point alone should the code be as in my updated question (I update the code according to your code)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yes. thanks for spotting it. that's what happens when you answer from mobile...